# Get textbox value from dynamically created table

Tags: jquery

I've got a table where I use Ajax to get the data from the database. After each line i've got a number of textboxes. I need the data from each line from the database and the data that is filled in manually in the textboxes. I can't get the data from the textboxes. I keep getting undefined, or an empty result. I've tried it with id's and classes, but without result. Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

This a what the table looks like

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvnjkgsx6k1k4es/PastedGraphic-1.png?dl=0

And this is part of my code

```
function opslaan() {
    $('#tabelddl tbody tr').each(function() {
        var cijfer1 = $(this).find(".vraag1").val();
    });
}
```

Here is the Ajax call

```
   $.ajax({
       url:"../php/zoek_opleiding_cijfer.php",
       type:"POST",
        async: false,
       data :
       {
           'opleidingid' : opleidingid
       },
       success: function(data) {
           var trHTML = '';
           $("#tabelddl tbody").remove();
           $.each(data,function(i,item) {
               trHTML += '<tr><td style="display:none;">' + data[i].opleiding_id +  
                 '</td><td style="display:none;">' + data[i].id +  
                 '</td><td style="display:none;">' + data[i].inschrijving_id +  
                 '</td><td style="display:none;">' + data[i].naam_opleiding +  
                 '</td><td>' + data[i].achternaam + '</td><td>' +  
                  data[i].tussenvoegsel + '</td><td>' + data[i].voornaam +  
                 '</td> <td class= "vraag1" id="vraag1" style="display:none;">' +  
                 '<input type="text"></td> </td>' + 
                 '</td> <td class= "vraag2" id="vraag2" style="display:none;">' +  
                 '<input type="textbox"></td> </td>' + 
                 '</td> <td class= "vraag3" id="vraag3" style="display:none;">' +  
                 '<input type="textbox"></td> </td>' + 
                 '</td> <td class= "vraag4" id="vraag4" style="display:none;">' +  
                 '<input type="textbox"></td> </td>' +  
                 '</td> <td class= "vraag5" id="vraag5" style="display:none;">' +  
                 '<input type="textbox"></td> </tr>';
           });
       $('#tabelddl').append(trHTML);
       },

       complete: function(){
       }
   });
```

And here is the table

```
<table class="table" id="tabelddl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="col-lg-1" style="display:none;">opleiding_id</th>
      <th class="col-lg-2" style="display:none;">relatie_id</th>
      <th class="col-lg-2" style="display:none;">inschrijving_id</th>
    <th class="col-lg-1" style="display:none;">naam_opleiding</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1">achternaam</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1">tussenvoegsel</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1">voornaam</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1" style="display:none;">vraag 1</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1" style="display:none;">vraag 2</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1" style="display:none;">vraag 3</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1" style="display:none;">vraag 4</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1" style="display:none;">vraag 5</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Try looking for `.find("#vraag1")` instead of the `.find(".vraag1")` - to look up an ID you need the # sign...

Comment: Where it will display the text? Directly in the `<td>` or in the `<input>` inside the `<td>` ?

Comment: can you able to provide your html part code

Comment: `.vraag1` is class name of your `td` and it dont have  `val()`

Comment: I've tried .find("#vraag1") and also things like $(this).find('td:nth-child(8)').text();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.vraag1` is class name of your td and it dont have `val()` so you can try like this `$(this).find(".vraag1 > input[type=text]").val();`

```js
$("document").ready(function(){

   $("#clickMe").click(function(){
       $('#tabelddl tbody tr').each(function() {      
           var cijfer1 = $(this).find(".vraag1 > input[type=text]").val();
            alert(cijfer1)
       })
   })


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabelddl">
<tr>
<td class="vraag1"> <input type="text"/></td>
<td class="vraag2"> <input type="text"/></td>
<td class="vraag3"> <input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="clickMe" id="clickMe"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working great! I've wasted so much time on this. Couldn't find the problem.

Comment: if its useful and solve your issue means mark it as correct answer